# Rolling resistance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, torque

Today, my physics teacher asked the following question (and gave it as homework):

> How can a moving body deaccelerate both in means of center of mass and rotationally?

I quickly answered that this happens due to rolling resistance and I gave as an example a car climbing a sand hill. Was I right? I would like to know!

My (draft) proof:

In the intersection points of the 2 surfaces the  2 surfaces don't have the same gradients ($\nabla S_p(x_i,y_i,z_i) \not= \nabla S_b(x_i,y_i,z_i)$) so there is a force applied to the solid by the plane wich can be analysed in two constituent forces then the one constituent force (Fy) parallel to the weight of the solid has the same magnitude with it so the total torque is:

$$\sum \tau = \|\vec w \times \vec \ell_1 \| + \|\vec F_y \times \vec \ell_2\| = w \cdot \mathrm d(\vec w, \vec F_y) < 0$$

and the center of mass deaccelerates as well:

$$\vec a = \frac{\sum \vec F}{m} = m^{-1} (\vec w_x + \vec F_x) \Rightarrow a < 0  $$ (as algebraic value)

PS Fx is the other constituent force

Comment: What reason do you have to think your proof might not be correct?

Comment: Is climbing a hill really a case of *rolling resistance* causing the slowing? There are several interesting question wrapping up in how rolling bodies slow when the problem is treated at a physics 101 level, so this is worth thinking about.

Comment: I would like to hear the opinion of the others on it